# How to restrain coloumn width to not to enlarge in case a responsive image added to a coloumn in a tabbed nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Zozo Tabs - http://zozoui.com/tabs/#templates - with Bootstrap 3.

I have several tabs in my page.

In one of my tabs, I created 2 coloumns with Bootstrap and put a img-responsive image.

However, when I put an image to the tab I realized that the width of the row enlarges.

When I switch to other tabs, which don't have images, behave same.

The problem persist even and only if I have an images inside a coloumn

This is my code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Left
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://patdollard.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ap_holder_121003_wg.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://patdollard.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ap_holder_121003_wg.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://patdollard.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ap_holder_121003_wg.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is my demo

http://jsfiddle.net/r8rFc/298/

This is my demonstration. Just look the first tab and after that other tabs.

Please focus on the first tab and when I switch to other.

[image]

Please find below more detailed video.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0p0v5idzzb3wl4/first_tab_problem.mov?dl=0

Comment: try `img .img-responsive{width:100%}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row is not enlarging. The scroll-bar is appearing only on the first tab because the images surpass the vertical space of the window. You can show the scroll-bar on your page at all times to prevent the slight jump/twitch by adding:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Tested in developer-tools and confirmed it works.

Comment: This is a solution but it seems a temporary way to do this. I don't want scroll-bar to be enabled all the time. Images shouldn't be surpassing the vertical space of the windows. I thought this is what is img-responsive for.

Comment: No, `img-responsive` only scales based on the `width` if you look at the bootstrap css: `{display:block;max-width:100%;height:auto}`.  Ideally, for tabbed sections like this, you design it so you the vertical scroll bar isn't an issue. Its a common problem. CSS-Tricks also recommends my solution - https://css-tricks.com/eliminate-jumps-in-horizontal-centering-by-forcing-a-scroll-bar/

Comment: Another solution maybe something like container-fluid - row-fluid. I will dig it now

Comment: `.container-fluid` still only applies: `{padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto}`,  when the scroll bar shows, it will still make the tabs jump. Its a vertical issue, not a horizontal issue.

Comment: It seems like this is the only solution. However I think there may be somehow a Jquery solution for this problem.

Comment: There really isn't an elegant solution. Basically, its the same as making your window about 15px smaller (when the scrollbar appears). You can use a plugin like http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/ to have a custom scroll bar that is fixed, so it goes on top of your content instead of pushing your content. I still recommend the above solution

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't opposed to using jQuery to solve this issue, here is another not so elegant option that doesn't force you to always show a scroll bar:

JS - Apply concrete values for centering page

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var margin = $(".container").offset().left;
  $(".container").css("margin", "0 0 0 " + margin + "px");
});
```

CSS - Nothing new. You should already have something functionally like this in your code.

```
.container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML - Nothing new, just for reference.

```
<div class="page-wrap"><!-- your page wrapper, maybe body tag -->
  <div class="container"><!-- the wrapper that has the auto margins -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7">LEFT SIDE</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://patdollard.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ap_holder_121003_wg.jpg" alt="" />
```

When the scroll bars appear, they cause shifting because it functionally changes the width of the container, so the auto margins has to be reset. When you load your page, you can check what value was calculated and just set that value as a hard margin.

Note: Doing this will require a window resize handler or your centering won't adjust properly.

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  var container = $(".container"),
      margin = container.css("margin", "0 auto").offset().left;

  container.css("margin", "0 0 0 " + margin + "px");
});
```

Comment: As you said this is not elegant way also. Since this is bootstrap, I don't want to play with container with that much for the sake of responsiveness. Will consider.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is with the vertical Scroll bar appearing. You can Either take all content to one page and disable it or add scroll bars to all the tabs using

```
overflow-y:
```